# ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback. onLost called with delay

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, android-connectivitymanager

I have `NetworkUtils` to monitor the connection state:

```
object NetworkUtils {
    lateinit var connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager

    var isConnected = false; private set

    private object NetworkCallback : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
            isConnected = true
        }

        override fun onLost(network: Network) {
            isConnected = false
        }
    }

    fun init(context: Context) {
        connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(ConnectivityManager::class.java)
    }

    fun isConnectedDeprecated(): Boolean {
        val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
        return networkInfo?.isConnected == true
    }

    fun registerNetworkCallback() = connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(NetworkCallback)
    fun unregisterNetworkCallback() = connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(NetworkCallback)
}
```

And Interceptor I use with Retrofit:

```
class MyInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        return try {
            chain.proceed(chain.request())
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throw if (NetworkUtils.isConnected()) {
                ExceptionA()
            } else {
                ExceptionB()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The point is to know if `IOException` thrown from request caused by no connection (`ExceptionB`) or if it's some other network issue (`ExceptionA`).

The issue is if I turn off WIFI on my device in the middle of the request I expect to get `ExceptionB`, but sometimes I get `ExceptionA`. Because when interceptor catches `IOException` `NetworkCallback`'s `onLost` isn't called yet.

I suspect that's because `By default, the callback methods are called on the connectivity thread of your app, which is a separate thread used by ConnectivityManager.` ([link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/reading-network-state#listening-events))
And Retorfit runs interceptors on a different thread. So there's no any guaranteed order.

So **is there a way to be sure that `NetworkCallback` will be hit before interceptor will catch the exception?**

I know we can pass in `Handler` when registering the `NetworkCallback`, and maybe that could help us to somehow run `NetworkCallback` on the same thread as Retrofit interceptors. But I have no idea how to do it and it looks like a bit dirty solution.

Also, if check `NetworkUtils.isConnectedDeprecated()` in interceptor instead of `NetworkUtils.isConnected` then it works exactly like I want to. But documentation says:
`Deprecated. Apps should instead use the ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback API to learn about connectivity changes. These will give a more accurate picture of the connectivity state of the device and let apps react more easily and quickly to changes.`

So it's not `more quickly` if `NetworkCallback` is called with some delay, huh?